# Where are angular functions being "stored"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am not sure if the following is a browser issue or bug however, if any function like following,

```
$scope.editSomething= function(){
  alert("hello");
}
```

Gets called always at the beginning and if I edit something, the webpage does what it is supposed to (alert hello). However, my breakpoint never reaches that point except when I load the page.

My question: Does scope store my functions? Or my debugger is just behaving weird?

Comment: Silly to ask, but where are you setting the breakpoint? JavaScript is only executed client side, so it makes sense for the breakpoint not to be hit until you load the page.

Comment: My guess would be your breakpoint is on the first line of the above snippet, which of course only runs when the controller is initialized, not when editSomething is executed.

Comment: Is this function referecned in the view?

Comment: Oh but I am confused how it is EXECUTING an action without going to the breakpoint. My breakpoint is on both the lines of the same code.

Comment: @KevinB, that makes sense! but how does it do the action ````alert("hello")````?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Neither do I. OP, could you please give a more comprehensive version of your code? That way we might stop losing some context here. Perhaps put it on JSfiddle to replicate the issue you're having (obviously, you can't set breakpoints there, but you can point out what you're trying to achieve with comments).

Comment: Sorry guys for the late reply but one person understood what I meant and answered what I want. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope stores the variables you place on it.

Variables can also store functions. In your case you are assigning an anonymous function to a variable named `editSomething`.

The code inside the controller is executed each time the controller is initialized. If you place your breakpoint on the line with `$scope.editSomething= function(){` you would hit the breakpoint every time the controller gets initialized (e.g. on page load).

If you want to see when the anonymous method stored in the `editSomething` variable is executed (for instance by placing an `ng-click=editSomething()` on an HTML element in your template and then clicking on it) then you should place your breakpoint on the `alert("hello");` line.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is how you are writing the Function. Writing it like this will make the function only executed when you call it:

https://jsfiddle.net/bgerhards/cu4wkaqf/

```
function Hello(something) {
 console.log(something);   
};

Hello("Hello World");
```

If you make a variable a function like you have, it will execute the function and put the return value in the variable

```
Hello2 = function() {
 return "Something Here";   
};

console.log("Hello2 Output: "+ Hello2());
```